Flickvideo player click on full screen then for 1 second its set landscape and again set it to porttrait issue. want to show landscape
I want to show videos in list view. I am using Flick Video Player. In this player, when I click on the full-screen video icon, the VideoView changes to landscape mode, but after 1 second, it switches back to portrait mode. i am remove all screen oriantation and also check with add all oriantation issue still exist below is code check and please comment your solution, i applied all soution from Chat GPT it's not working for me.
VideoList Screen

class VideoListScreen extends GetWidget<VideoListController> {
  final VideoListController vidListController = Get.put(VideoListController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: GetBuilder(
        builder: (VideoListController rtc) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 20.h),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.h),
                  height: 30.h,
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(width: 15.w),
                    itemCount: rtc.authorName.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final String feeling = rtc.authorName[index];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () => rtc.toggleAuthorSelection(feeling),
                        child: _buildTabRow(
                          feeling: feeling,
                          isSelected: rtc.isAuthorSelected(feeling),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 12.h, vertical: 10.h),
                    itemCount: rtc.displayedVideos.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: FlickMultiPlayer(
                                url: vidListController
                                    .displayedVideos[index].videoUrl,
                                flickMultiManager: vidListController
                                    .flickMultiManager,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 10.h),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4.h),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment:
                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              mainAxisAlignment:
                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  rtc.displayedVideos[index].title,
                                  style: CustomTextStyles
                                      .bodyLargeGray5000122,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 15.h),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: rtc.displayedVideos.length == 0,
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "No Data Found",
                        style: CustomTextStyles.titleLargeBluegray80024,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTabRow({
    required String feeling,
    required bool isSelected,
  }) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.h, vertical: 8.h),
      decoration: AppDecoration.outlineBlueGray.copyWith(
        borderRadius: BorderRadiusStyle.circleBorder30,
        color: isSelected ? appTheme.pink50 : Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.h),
        child: Text(
          feeling.tr,
          style: theme.textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
            color: appTheme.blueGray90001,
            fontSize: 12.fSize,
            fontWeight: isSelected ? FontWeight.w600 : FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Flick multi manager
import 'package:flick_video_player/flick_video_player.dart';

class FlickMultiManager {
  List<FlickManager> _flickManagers = [];
  FlickManager? _activeManager;
  bool _isMute = false;
  List<FlickManager> get flickManagers => _flickManagers;

  init(FlickManager flickManager) {
    _flickManagers.add(flickManager);
    if (_isMute) {
      flickManager.flickControlManager?.mute();
    } else {
      flickManager.flickControlManager?.unmute();
    }
    if (_flickManagers.length == 1) {
      play(flickManager);
    }
  }

  remove(FlickManager flickManager) {
    if (_activeManager == flickManager) {
      _activeManager = null;
    }
    flickManager.dispose();
    _flickManagers.remove(flickManager);
  }

  togglePlay(FlickManager flickManager) {
    if (_activeManager?.flickVideoManager?.isPlaying == true &&
        flickManager == _activeManager) {
      pause();
    } else {
      play(flickManager);
    }
  }

  pause() {
    _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.pause();
  }

  play([FlickManager? flickManager]) {
    if (flickManager != null) {
      _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.pause();
      _activeManager = flickManager;
    }

    if (_isMute) {
      _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.mute();
    } else {
      _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.unmute();
    }

    _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.play();
  }

  toggleMute() {
    _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.toggleMute();
    _isMute = _activeManager?.flickControlManager?.isMute ?? false;
    if (_isMute) {
      _flickManagers.forEach((manager) => manager.flickControlManager?.mute());
    } else {
      _flickManagers
          .forEach((manager) => manager.flickControlManager?.unmute());
    }
  }
}


Flickmulti manager
class FlickMultiPlayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const FlickMultiPlayer(
      {Key? key,
      required this.url,
      required this.flickMultiManager})
      : super(key: key);

  final String url;
  final FlickMultiManager flickMultiManager;

  @override
  _FlickMultiPlayerState createState() => _FlickMultiPlayerState();
}

class _FlickMultiPlayerState extends State<FlickMultiPlayer> {
  late FlickManager flickManager;

  @override
  void initState() {
    flickManager = FlickManager(
      videoPlayerController:
          VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse(widget.url))
            ..setLooping(false),
      autoPlay: false,
    );

    widget.flickMultiManager.init(flickManager);

    super.initState();
  }

  void _initializeVideo() {
    /*setState(() {
      hasError = false;
    });*/


  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.flickMultiManager.remove(flickManager);
    //flickManager.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FlickVideoPlayer(
        flickManager: flickManager,
          flickVideoWithControls: FlickVideoWithControls(
            controls: FlickPortraitControls(),
          ),
          flickVideoWithControlsFullscreen: FlickVideoWithControls(
            controls: FlickLandscapeControls(),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }


}


Please give me solution for that or give me alternet way to achive this functionality.
Thanks in advance.
